# How to pass submit button name and value in post request if yii confirmation dialog is used?

Tags: php, yii

Then I don't use yii confirmation dialog i can see submit button's name and value in post request.
If I use yii confirmation dialog i can't see submit button's name and value in post request.

How to see them when yii confirmation dialog is used?

For example, if form contains such button:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('name', ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'submitButtonValue']); ?>
```

It will have such post attributes:

```
 ["action"]=> string(12) "submitButtonValue"
```

On the other hand, if form contains button with yii confirmation dialog:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('name', ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'submitButtonValue',
                            'data' => [
                                'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
                                'method' => 'post'
                            ],
]); ?>
```

It wont contain "action=>'submitButtonValue'" attribute in the post request.

I tried to put name and value in data section, but it did not help.

```
'data' => [
   'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
   'method' => 'post',
   'name' => 'action',
   'value' => 'submitButtonValue'
],
```

Edit: Meaning of giving name and value to submit button is to distinguish if several of them is used.

Comment: Difficulties with data-attributes and HtmlHelper are mostly caused by [RenderTagAttributes()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#submitButton()-detail).

Comment: What is wrong with it related to my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gubberrr for pushing me to dig deeper.
As occured problem was specific to my project. Client scripts were disabled globally and that is why yii.activeForm.js file wasn't present in view, which add hidden input field with name and value set on submit button.

First solution to the problem is to enable client scripts at least in current form:

```
<?php ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientScript' => true]); ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Delete', ['name' => 'action', 'value' => 'submitButtonValue',
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
        'method' => 'POST',
    ],
]); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Second solution doesn't require yii.activeForm.js but yii.js which is included with YiiAsset registration and create input field for data-params attributes.

```
<?php \yii\web\YiiAsset::register($this); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Delete', [
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'params' => ['action' => 'submitButtonValue'],
    ],
]); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, writing the data-attributes explicitly:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('name', [
           'name' => 'action', 
           'value' => 'submitButtonValue', 
           'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure?', 
           'data-method' => 'post',
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Same result. It wont ask for confirmation without ```\yii\web\YiiAsset::register($this);``` but with it it will have no attributes in post.

Comment: Are you using it in an activeform or just as a standalone submitbutton?

    `<?php ActiveForm::begin() ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('name', [
        'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'submitButtonValue',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
            'method' => 'post'
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>`

Comment: I use it in ActiveForm

Comment: You can try adding  `Html::hiddenInput('action', ['value' => 'submitButtonValue'])` to the form.

Comment: The point of adding name and value is to distinguish when several submit buttons with different purpose is used. So you can't add one hidden input to fit them all.

Comment: I see, 
Are you using it inside pjax-tags? 
Maybe inside a gridview with pjax set true? In this case, pjax could mess with data-attributes. (eg. tooltip not showing, ...): set in options-array 'pjax' => "0".

Comment: No, I use no pjax here. Have you tried to reproduce the issue or just giving pieces of advice even not knowing precisely the bad case scenario?

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce the issue, I'm just helping you to figure it out: more details could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hiddenInput to your form.

```
    <?= Html::hiddenInput('action', ['value' => 'submitButtonValue']); ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('name', ['data' => [
              'confirm' =>'Are you sure?',  
              'method' => 'post',
              ]]); ?>
```

Comment: Purpose of naming submit button is to distinguish between several of them. Hidden input can't make them all work.